# When setting up local node for HEDERA, some containers not running, ports are not available

Tags: docker, docker-compose, window, hedera-hashgraph

I'm running docker inside visual studio on a window machine. This is the response after I put in command: docker-compose up d. I'm very new to this. I appreciate any helps very much.

```
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_ETH_POPULATE_SYNTHETIC_CONTRACT_RESULTS\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_WS_CONNECTION_LIMIT_PER_IP\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_WS_MULTIPLE_ADDRESSES_ENABLED\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_ETH_POPULATE_SYNTHETIC_CONTRACT_RESULTS\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_WS_CONNECTION_LIMIT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_WS_MAX_INACTIVITY_TTL\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-02-28T21:11:13+07:00" level=warning msg="The \"RELAY_WS_SUBSCRIPTION_LIMIT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
[+] Running 13/0
 ✔ Container minio                      Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container haveged                    Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container prometheus                 Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container hedera-explorer            Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container mirror-node-db             Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container relay-cache                Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container record-sidecar-uploader    Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container record-streams-uploader    Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container grafana                    Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container mirror-node-importer       Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container mirror-node-rest           Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container mirror-node-web3           Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 ✔ Container account-balances-uploader  Running                                                                                                           0.0s 
 - Container envoy-proxy                Starting                                                                                                          0.0s 
 - Container network-node               Starting                                                                                                          0.0s 
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:50213 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:50213: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
PS C:\Users\david\Hedera\hedera-local-node-main>
```

First there was 1 container not running. I tried restart the program and run the command again but instead of 1 container not running, there are 2.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Can you share your `docker-compose.yml`  file please ?

Comment: Hello there, thanks for reaching out, this is the file I posted on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/sqs6GyaS

Comment: Do you have any other process running that already has port `50213` open?